# Using a Ranking in one column to lookup names in another column and put in rank order in a 3rd column

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to create a formula that will use a ranking (K2:K11) or the name of the ranking (L2:L11) and then match it to the respective name from A2:A11.  The problem I am having is I am not sure how to write it and then match it to a different column.  I thought INDEX and MATCH would work but that is only one condition.  For example, I want to rank the players in order of their Plus/Minus and then it has to match the rank to the name in a different column and put it in rank order in Column M if that makes sense. I've searched for index and match and vlookup but I believe I have to nest them but not sure how.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1A4d_DfzTADMXU6OEnRPv8E6_NqMW7VjK-Rng-3gCdIA/edit?usp=sharing

Thanks for any help in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use SORT for this. You set the column you want to sort, by which you want it sort it by and if it's ascending or not:

```
=SORT(A2:A11,J2:J11,0)
```

[image]

Would that be useful?

Comment: That works great!  Thank you- I never thought of just using SORT!